# Best way to deal with chipped paint

Tags: hyundai, paint, tucson

I bought a Hyundai Tucson 2023 a few months ago. Yesterday, I noticed chipped paint on the car's bonnet (see pictures below). I am not gonna lie; my heart sank. I am not sure what caused the chip but my intuition is it may have been a small rock or something. The chip is very small and is only noticeable up close. I looked on the internet for solutions to this and found a [touch up paint pen](https://hyundaishop.com/hyundai-touch-up-paint-pen-z073). The store matches the pen with the color of the car using the VIN number. I ordered the pen but I am now hesitant about applying the paint from the pen before asking whether that is the best way to deal with this problem. Can I do something else? Also, how can I avoid this from happening going forward?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I don't know how to tell you to apply the pen, but would highly suggest once you get that figured out, you put on something called a "clear bra". I think 3M makes it. It applies like a wrap, but is clear protection for the front of your car. If applied properly, you cannot see it and won't know it's there unless you know. It'll protect the paint until you take it off.